# On Sizing and Positioning Drop Caps

Tags: formatting, lettrine, drop-cap

I would like to make use of drop caps so that they appear as follows:

[image]

Unfortunately, with the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\begin{document}
\large
\lettrine[lines=3]{\color{Red}{\initfamily{A}}}{\color{Red}s} the inclinations and judgments of writers have been different, so have they disposed themselves to treat of different matters.---Some, charmed with the beauty of eloquence,
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I would like to be able to:

1. increase the size of the drop cap to resemble that given by the first output;
2. and have the rest of the sentence begin below the top of the drop cap as illustrated again in  the first output *(It seems that when `lines=3` is specified, it does not mean that the output will be the same)*.

Would someone show me how this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: There is other options for \lettrine. f.e. loversize.

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\DefaultLoversize}{0.1}` will increase the size of the lettrine by 10%, but I can’t reproduce the problem you’re experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code (as below)

```
% lettrineprob.tex  SE 567648
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\begin{document}
\large
\lettrine[lines=3]{\color{Red}{\initfamily{A}}}{\color{Red}s} the inclinations
 and judgments of writers have been different, so have they disposed 
 themselves to treat of different matters.---Some, charmed with the beauty of
 eloquence,
\end{document}
```

and got this result, which seems to be what you are after.

[image]

Comment: That’s what I got too. Must be something about the O.P.’s default paper size or package versions that’s unusual.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I'm looking for, but when I run the code I posted, I get the undesirable output. Thank you for checking though.