# Why Does Merely Invoking a Package in the Preamble Alter the Output?

Tags: fonts, output

My subsequent question is something I encountered today and is related to the post:

[On Sizing and Positioning Drop Caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567648/on-sizing-and-positioning-drop-caps)

Using the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{accanthis}
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\begin{document}
\large
\lettrine[lines=3]{\color{blue}{\initfamily{W}}}{\color{blue}hy} does this strange thing happen when a package is merely added to the preamble and never invoked? \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

Whereas, merely adding the package `accanthis` to the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{accanthis}
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\begin{document}
\large
\lettrine[lines=3]{\color{blue}{\initfamily{W}}}{\color{blue}hy} does this strange thing happen when a package is merely added to the preamble and never invoked? \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I *emphasize* that I never called for the said font within the document, yet the output was changed anyway.

Does anyone have an explanation? Or better still, can relate how I may prevent such an occurrence from happening until I call for it in the document?

Finally, I remark that I have encountered similar problems before, but today I have a specific short example to relate. (This may explain, in part, the *drop cap* problem I posted yesterday [On Sizing and Positioning Drop Caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567648/on-sizing-and-positioning-drop-caps) although I do not know for certain what font was used to produce the paragraph containing the larger drop cap that I want to imitate.)

Thank you.

Comment: Loading a font-related package could necessarily change the font. That doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: the package changes the default font, that is by design.

Comment: Unrelated: maths in `$ .. $` aren't rendered in posts here on the site. But even if it were, you should use `*text*` not `$text$` to emphasize text.

Comment: A lot of packages set something that can potentially change text, even in stronger ways than changing a font. Load Spanish `babel` with default options and see any `'n` becoming `ñ`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have pointed out why this happens. As for your question about preventing it from happening, you could just save the value of `\rmdefault` before loading `accanthis` and restore it afterwards:

```
\let\savedrmdefault\rmdefault
\usepackage{accanthis}
\let\rmdefault\savedrmdefault
```

You can still switch to Accanthis using `\accanthis`, e.g.,

```
This is in Latin/Computer Modern Roman.
{\accanthis This is in Accanthis.}
This is Latin/Computer Modern Roman.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly!